# What does it mean if memory_limit in php.ini is set to -1?

Tags: php, ini

The php version is 7.4. Does this mean that the memory allocated is unlimited?

Comment: [PHP core directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Answer (score 0):

It literally says so [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in the official doc.

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is
> allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for
> eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no
> memory limit, set this directive to -1.